# What is this thing similar to KleisliFunctor?

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, category-theory

Here is how we can define [`KleisliFunctor`](https://elvishjerricco.github.io/2016/10/12/kleisli-functors.html):

```
class (Monad m, Functor f) => KleisliFunctor m f where
  kmap :: (a -> m b) -> f a -> f b
  kmap f = kjoin . fmap f

  kjoin :: f (m a) -> f a
  kjoin = kmap id
```

Does this type class

```
class (Functor f, Monad m) => Absorb f m where
  (>>~) :: f a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  a >>~ f = ajoin $ fmap f a

  ajoin :: f (m a) -> m a
  ajoin a = a >>~ id
```

fit somewhere into category theory? What are the laws? Are they

```
a >>~ g . f     === fmap f a >>~ g
a >>~ (f >=> g) === a >>~ f >>= g
```

?

Comment: Do you have some particular example type that permits an `Absorb` instance but no sufficiently powerful standard instances to implement `(>>~)` and `ajoin` with?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I need `Absorb` in order to implement generalized monadic folding that allows to keep an accumulator in the `f` functor, but return the result in the `m` monad. See e.g. [this](https://github.com/effectfully/prefolds/blob/374257b12f9a2af752862addafe456cded9c0efb/test/Main.hs#L297).

Answer (score 4):

*This is a speculative answer. Proceed with caution.*

Let's first consider `KleisliFunctor`, focusing on the bind-like arrow mapping:

```
class (Monad m, Functor f) => KleisliFunctor m f where
  kmap :: (a -> m b) -> f a -> f b
```

For this to actually be a functor from the Kleisli category of `m` to **Hask**, `kmap` has to follow the relevant functor laws:

```
-- Mapping the identity gives identity (in the other category).
kmap return = id
-- Mapping a composed arrow gives a composed arrow (in the other category).
kmap (g <=< f) = kmap g . kmap f
```

The fact that there are two `Functor`s involved makes things a little unusual, but not unreasonable -- for instance, the laws do hold for `mapMaybe`, which is the first concrete example the `KleisliFunctor` post alludes to.

As for `Absorb`, I will flip the bind-like method for the sake of clarity:

```
class (Functor f, Monad m) => Absorb f m where
  (~<<) :: (a -> m b) -> f a -> m b
```

If we are looking for something analogous to `KleisliFunctor`, a question that immediately arises is which category would have functions of type `f a -> m b` as arrows. It certainly cannot be **Hask**, as its identity (of type `f a -> m a`) cannot be `id`. We would have to figure out not only identity but also composition. For something that is not entirely unlike `Monad`...

```
idAbsorb :: f a -> m a
compAbsorb :: (f b -> m c) -> (f a -> m b) -> (f a -> m c)
```

... the only plausible thing I can think of right now is having a monad morphism as `idAbsorb` and using a second monad morphism in the opposite direction (that is, from `m` to `f`) so that `compAbsorb` can be implemented by applying the first function, then going back to `f` and finally applying the second function. We would need to work that out in order to see if my assumptions are appropriate, if this approach works, and if it leads to something useful for your purposes.

Comment: "which category would have functions of type `f a -> m b` as arrows" — I don't know about arrows, but aren't these objects in the comma category of two endofunctors on `Hask`: `f` and `m`? No idea what it gives us, though. `compAbsorb` is very unsatisfying for me: for one, I don't want `f b -> m c` to be a monad morphism as my `f` has a rather dummy monad instance, for two, my use case (see the comment under the question) doesn't require going from `m` to `f` and I don't want to impose that. Thanks for the answer, it has clarified some things to me.

Comment: @user3237465 Looking at your code seems to confirm your expectations. In particular, trying to do the "obvious" thing by trying `idAbsorb = slift` and `compAbsorb = g . runDriveT . f` falls at the first hurdle -- `compAbsorb idAbsorb f` is not `f` (it changes `Stop` into `More`), and so we don't even have a category. Going from `DriveT m` to `m` causes trouble, and, as you say, it makes little sense to do that during composition in your use case. By the way, note that your `(>~>)` is neither `(>=>)` nor `flip compAbsorb`, which seems to confirm that you want something else indeed.