# Is there a common name for this generalization of monads?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In Haskell, we think of a monad `m` as being a (Hask endo-)functor equipped with the following structure:

```
pure : a -> m a
bind : (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)
```

This is by contrast to the more categorical approach, where we tend to think in terms of `join` rather than `bind`. However, the `bind`-style monad admits a generalization that the `join`-style monad doesn't. In particular, we can consider pairs of functors `f` and `m` equipped with the following structure:

```
pure : a -> m a
fdom : (a -> m b) -> (f a -> m b)
```

Is there a name for these sorts of functor-pairs in category theory?

NB: I'm not entirely sure how to make the details of this construction work in category theory in general, b/c if I let `m` and `f` be arbitrary functors as opposed to just endofunctors on Hask then I think I might need to start working in 2-categories in order to even be able to name `pure` and `fdom`. I was hoping to find some papers on related concepts and start reading, but the popularity of monads has made this concept exceptionally difficult to google.

Comment: (1) "However, the `bind`-style monad admits a generalization that the `join`-style monad doesn't" -- Or does it? What about `fdom id :: f (m a) -> m a`? (I have no idea if that actually leads somewhere; I'm just speculating about type signatures.) (2) Related: [*What is this thing similar to KleisliFunctor?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40716239/2751851) -- but note that my answer there is not particularly useful.

Comment: This sounds related to Kan extensions but my knowledge of it stops right here https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2/docs/Data-Functor-Kan-Ran.html

Comment: What laws do you propose for this structure?

Comment: Given `fdom g as`, I can see you'd map `g` over the `as`, but then what? What does `fdom` do to reduce the resulting `f (m b)` value to a `m b` value? Seems like you need a functor/algebra/monad triple, rather than just a functor/monad pair.